# Hadoop CompositeInputFormat block matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: java, hadoop, matrix-multiplication, pagerank

I am trying to implement a block matrix-vector multiplication algorithm with Hadoop according to the schematics from http://i.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch5.pdf page 162. My matrix is going to be sparse and the vector dense which is exactly what is required in PageRank as well. The vector is assumed to not fit in memory.

The way I was thinking about a possible implementation is to use CompositeInputFormat and basically perform a map-side join of a matrix block with a vector block and sum up the intermediate result blocks that contribute to the final result block in the combiner/reducer. The difference between this approach and a general map-side join is that I would need to join several blocks of the matrix with a single block of the vector. I know about the requirements of a map-side join in Hadoop concerning splits, ordering etc. and in terms of splitting I would take care of that by having one file for each block named accordingly. To me it looks like I need to modify the code that determines which files shall be joined so Hadoop wouldn't want to join files from the two paths with the same name anymore, but rather according to my defined scheme. However, I don't know if that's a valid approach and where this part of the code is located. I looked into the Hadoop source, but couldn't find it.

I know that I could do this with a reduce-side join, but efficiency is critical here because this matrix-vector multiplication needs to be executed in large amounts. Distributed Cache is out of the question because the vector doesn't fit in memory.

Does anyone have an idea how to tackle this problem?

Comment: It is simply enough to partition on Vertex basis (a vertex and its outlinks in a single row). I haven't seen such a complicated pagerank algorithm like you require yet. Treating the whole thing as a sparse matrix vector multiplication makes it even worse.

Comment: Well, the situation is that I just need to execute the matrix-vector multiplication LIKE in this PageRank example. I'm not implementing PageRank. The strategy described in the PDF seems quite efficient given I'm able to realize it efficiently. I feel CompositeInputFormat is almost what I need only with some modification in the matching of the files to be joined. But I'm not sure if that's correct and if so how to do this modification.

Comment: @sigurd - did you manage to solve it? If yes, how?